# Basic Tensor Manipulation

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus

In one of my assignments for GR there is a question as follows:
Consider the equation
$$A^{\alpha}_{\mu \nu}B^{\mu \nu} = C^{\alpha}$$
where B is a second rank anti-symmetric tensor and C is a vector.
From this I am able to prove that $$(A^{\alpha}_{\mu \nu} - A^{\alpha}_{\nu \mu})$$ is a tensor.
But can I say anything about $$(A^{\alpha}_{\mu \nu} + A^{\alpha}_{\nu \mu})$$ from this ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.

You can always write:

$$
A^\alpha_{\mu\nu}=S^\alpha_{\mu\nu}+X^{\alpha}_{\mu\nu}
$$

Where

$$
S^\alpha_{\mu\nu}=\left(A^\alpha_{\mu\nu}+A^\alpha_{\nu\mu}\right)/2
$$

is the symmetric part, whilst:

$$
X^\alpha_{\mu\nu}=\left(A^\alpha_{\mu\nu}-A^\alpha_{\nu\mu}\right)/2
$$

is the antisymmetric part. Treating the two parts as independent you get:

$$
\begin{align}
X^\alpha_{\mu\nu}B^{\mu\nu}=&C^\alpha \\
S^\alpha_{\mu\nu}B^{\mu\nu}=&0\,\forall \alpha
\end{align}
$$

The last equation admits non-tensorial solutions for $S^\alpha_{\mu\nu}$.

Whilst slightly different, there are examples of such things. For example the connection $\Gamma^\alpha_{\beta\gamma}$ is not a tensor, but its anti-symmetric part (torsion: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_tensor) is.